# How are `IF` and `AND` statements evaluated in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

In Java or C#, `AND` statements are evaluated from left to right. If the first condition is not true, then the second condition is not evaluated. Which is useful if your second condition will cause an `java.lang.arrayindexoutofboundsexception`.

I have a similar case in my Excel-VBA application. I have an if statement as such:

`If condition1 = false And  cellElement - 1 <> "" Then` ...

It throws a `VBA - Run Time Error 1004 'Application Defined or Object Defined Error'`, even if `condition1` is false.

My question is, does VBA evaluate the second condition in an AND statement, even if the first condition is false?

My current work around is ugly, but it works:

```
Dim b As Boolean
If condition1 = false Then
   b = false
Else
   b = cellElement - 1 <> ""

If b Then...
```

Thank you!

Comment: Ther's no short-circuiting in VBA

Comment: You have three conditions in your "two condition AND statement"... (2 equal signs and 1 not-equal sign)

Comment: You're right @Chrismas007, thank you, I fixed it. That's not how I actually had in my application though.